# Skip particular (specified) iteration of for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, numerical-methods

I'm pretty new to C++ but I couldn't find a workaround for this online, I feel like there might be an interesting, elegant solution possible for this.

I'm ultimately trying to code a leapfrog algorithm for planetary motion. I've defined a class called planet

```
Planet(double mass, double x0, double x1, double v0, double v1)
```

and I've got an array storing information for 4 different planets:

```
Planet planets[] = {
Planet(2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.94, 0.65),
Planet(1.0, -0.6, -0.2, 1.86, 0.7),
Planet(1.0, 0.5, 1.0, -0.44, -1.40),
Planet(0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 1.15, -1.50)
};
```

I'm going to want to calculate the force due to gravity of each planet on every other planet. This involves implementing the mathematical equation for the force on planet i: F_i= sum over i!=j of [(G*m_i*m_j)/r_ij], where i and j denote two planets, j being incremented each time, and r_ij the distance between the two.

Before I start thinking about that as a whole, I was testing if I could use a for loop to select a particular planet from the array, and a particular component from that planet, and print that. That works fine via

```
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
}
```

However, I wanted to try exclude a particular planet, say I was computing the force on j where j=2.

```
for(int i=0; (i<j || i>j) && i<4; ++i){
cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
}
```

This loop terminates at 2, only printing the v0 value (as defined via the class) for p[0] and p[1], not p[3] as well as I'd have liked. Likewise, j=1 only prints v0 for p[0] and p[1].

Is there a convenient way to put a condition within the for loop which meets my needs or should I rethink my approach?

Comment: The condition you put in the for loop indicates when it finishes, therefore when i reaches 2, it will end (2<2 == false). That's why it only gets to print p[0] and p[1].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try this

```
for(int i=0; i<4 ; ++i)
 {
   if( i != j )
   cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
 }
```

This is the simplest method I could think of without trying anything complex. You just have to check whether `i` is equal to `j` inside the loop. If `i` is not equal to `j`, then give output.

If you don't want this, then you can use `continue` like it has been suggested in the other answers.

```
for(int i=0; i<4 ; ++i)
 {
  if ( i == j )
  continue;
  cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just put the check inside the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
   if (i!=j) {
      cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of suggestions were made above, but why didn't your code work??

```
for(int i=0; (i<j || i>j) && i<4; ++i){
  cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
}
```

Remember the loop will continue to execute as long as the loop condition is true; once the loop condition becomes false the loop will quit. Your loop condition is

```
(i<j || i>j) && i<4
```

For this expression to be true both sub-expressions on either side of the "&&" must be true. When i=j the

```
(i<j || i>j)
```

expression is false, so the loop condition is false and the loop terminates, just as you observed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword [continue](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_continue_statement.htm) inside for loop. It forces the next iteration of the loop

```
if(i==j) continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the loop to *skip* the inner behaviour when `i == j`, then make use of the `continue` keyword:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i == j) {
        continue;
    }
    cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
}
```

Which will cause the loop body to be skipped. Another way is to only execute the inner logic when `i != j`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i != j) {
        cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Both ways achieve the same goal.

Comment: "make the for loop go back to the start". I'd think about rewording that. It makes it sound like `i` will go back to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* insist on having it in the for meta (as opposed to in the loop), try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i + 1 == j ? i++ : i += 2)
```

However, using `if (i == j) continue;` is probably the cleanest way of writing it.